# How to narrow down a union return type from a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below code and I am not able to narrow down the type even with the `is` operator. I tried using the `isPerson` fn to state that it is a `Person type`, but within the function, how do I access a specific property to know if it is this type?

playground code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=7&pln=13&pc=15#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyycA5hAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcBAvgQaJLIigIIhgdOABt8RZAiyisUKhjBRQpdp2khFySFoC8yABRwopKuijZcAH2SDhYgJRnMOZDbsjxugHwTiUCDAaKFxjUlYOAg0tYAxzS2R9A1o6ZwtXdyFPJ2p6ZFi0F1wfP2QAoJDkAEIqlIA6MggIzgA3Y2QAByLE7QhFAzwScioARgAmZDYHVi4YA1j4nAMu9JAHB0JiFcsG8magA

```
interface Person {
  age: number;
}

interface Animal {
  color: string
}

const test = (arg: Person | Animal): Person | Animal => {
  return arg;
}

const isPerson = (num: Person | Animal): num is Person => {
  return !!num.age;
}

var person = test({ age: 12 });

if(isPerson(person)){
  person.age;
}
```

The error that i get in isPerson is

```
Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Person | Animal'.
  Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Animal'.(2339)
```

Comment: `return num.hasOwnProperty("age");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like the fact that your `num` argument might be an `Animal` and thus not have an `age` property.

One approach would be to use the [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
const isPerson = (num: Person | Animal): num is Person => {
  return 'age' in num;
}
```

The difference with your code is that it evaluates the edge case where the `age` property is present but has a value of `0` differently.